# How to identify subset of rows containing only 'MISSING' and zeroes ('0') in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I created a dataset by joining multiple tables to a primary table containing department_id and year. The final data frame had a lot of missing values which I then imputed with 'MISSING' for categorical and with '0'(zero) for continuous variables.

I now want to remove the subset of rows that are populated with either 'MISSING' or '0' (i.e. have no other values), how can I do this in R?

Thanks

Comment: Something like this: `df %>% filter(categorical != 'MISSING', numeric != 0)`.  But I suggest you go back to the merge step, leave out the imputations, and remove the missings directly.  (Maybe inner join instead?)  Currently you can only remove zeros, not just those zeros that were missing to begin with.

Comment: Thank You Ott for your suggestions. Maybe I was not very clear in my post, I want to remove only those rows that are fully null (i.e. either 'MISSING' or '0's), but want to keep rows with partial values, even if it had only 1 value. 
I will try an inner join and see how it goes and update.

Comment: The line above should do exactly that.  I'd still recommend to delete first and impute later though.

Comment: Yes, sorry, did not think about you need OR, not AND.  See below for correct solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest leaving your `NA`s the way they are if you can. R has built-in generic functions for dealing with `NA`s across classes that can make your life much easier. If your missings are indicated by different values for each data type then you'll need to add a comparison for each type of missing, which isn't very efficient.

*It's also worth mentioning that the options below are generalizable, i.e. they will work on data frames with any number of columns, so you don't need to add a comparison for each new column.*

First, generate some data to test with:

```r
df <- data.frame(num = c(1, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5),
                 cat = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "MISSING", "MISSING")
                 )

#### OUTPUT ####
  num     cat
1   1       a
2   0       b # <- keep
3   3       c
4   4       d
5   0 MISSING # <- drop
6   5 MISSING # <- keep
```

You can filter using base R or `dplyr` (among other options):

```r
# Base R option
df[rowSums(df == "MISSING" | df == 0) < ncol(df),]

# Tidyverse option using dplyr
library(dplyr)
filter_all(df, any_vars(!(. == "MISSING" | . == 0)))
```

The output for both options will look like this:

```
  num     cat
1   1       a
2   0       b # <- kept
3   3       c
4   4       d
5   5 MISSING # <- kept
```

Just for the sake of argument, here's how you can simplify things by leaving `NA`s as they are. First some new data:

```r
df_na <- data.frame(num = c(1, NA, 3, 4, NA, 5),
                    cat = c("a", "b", "c", "d", NA, NA)
                    )

#### OUTPUT ####
  num  cat
1   1    a
2  NA    b # <- keep
3   3    c
4   4    d
5  NA <NA> # <- drop
6   5 <NA> # <- keep
```

Now we can use the same strategies as above, but we only need to use `is.na()` rather than adding a comparison for each type of missing value:

```r
# Using base R
df_na[rowSums(is.na(df_na)) < ncol(df_na),]

# Using dplyr
library(dplyr)
filter_all(df_na, any_vars(!is.na(.)))

#### OUTPUT ####
  num  cat
1   1    a
2  NA    b # <- kept
3   3    c
4   4    d
6   5 <NA> # <- kept
```

Comment: perfect!!! thank you gersht, this was exactly what I was after. From what you mentioned, I understand that this method will not be very efficient if the missings are indicated by different values for each data. Fortunately, in this case, I only have "0" and "MISSING" so the method you suggested works well.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that Ott's solution doesn't do what they say it does. Here's his solution implemented correctly, in base R and in `dplyr`. Note that you will have to duplicate each `!= 0` clause for each of your columns.

```
# create some dummy data
data <- data.frame(
numeric = c(1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5, 6),
categorical = c("MISSING", "A", "B", "MISSING", "C", "MISSING", "D", "MISSING", "E")
)

# base R solution
data[data$numeric != 0 | data$categorical != "MISSING", ]

# dplyr solution
filter(data, numeric != 0 | categorical != "MISSING")
```